# Composer autoloads classes of TYPO3 extension without any autoload configuration

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

Why does the following root `composer.json` result in an `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` containing all the class mappings for Smarty's classes – although the `composer.json` of `typo3-ter/smarty` does not come with any `autoload` configuration?

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://composer.typo3.org"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
      "typo3/cms": "^6.2",
      "typo3-ter/smarty": "2.1.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some background info:

https://composer.typo3.org is a composer repository, which enables **legacy** TYPO3 Extension Repository (TER) extensions to be installable via composer. Because TER extensions do not have a vendor name, **all** of them share the same vendor, which is "typo3-ter".

This (legacy) composer repository is built by using meta information (dependencies to other TER extensions and TYPO3 versions, author, description …) from TER.

To make this repository more useful for end users and especially because TYPO3 >7.6 completely relies on the composer autoloader when installed via composer, the [complete extension directory](https://github.com/TYPO3/CmsComposerPackageGenerator/blob/master/src/Classes/Command/CreateTerExtensionJsonCommand.php#L146-L154) is added to the composer classmap. Without that, extension classes would not be loadable at all, without any additional configuration.

Because this can cause trouble, I taught TER to partially capture information from composer.json in case this file is present. This means **if** a composer.json is present **and** [it contains an autoload section](https://github.com/TYPO3/CmsComposerPackageGenerator/blob/master/src/Classes/Command/CreateTerExtensionJsonCommand.php#L155-L160), this section is used to generate the autoload information for this extension on composer.typo3.org

Regarding the smarty extension:

Surprisingly this extension has a composer.json file already. But it is broken. First and foremost: It misses autoload information, although it clearly has classes available. Because of the lack of autoload information, the composer.typo3.org package generator adds the complete directory as classmap.

If this causes trouble (you never mentioned that, but I assume so), you should add the [repo](https://github.com/rtp-ch/smarty) directly as type "vcs" to your composer.json and require "rtp/smarty" instead of "typo3-ter/smarty".

Or you ask the author to fix the composer.json and upload a new version to TER, or even better register that package directly on packagist.org

Comment: Thx. Do I understand this correctly? The TYPO3 CMS Composer Package Generator generates a `packages.json` and something like `all$0877d76abecf1f9f1412fa11915899533a4475b3.json` which are downloaded (really? it's 36 mb) by Composer on `composer update`. These files contain the autoload configuration which is used to build the Composer autoloader for my project. The `autoload` section in the TYPO3 extension's `composer.json` will not be taken into account on `composer update` at all – it is the the information in `all$0877d76abecf1f9f1412fa11915899533a4475b3.json` that is used. Right?

Comment: Yes, that package.json is generated and composer needs to download the complete file. There is an update pending to optimize this https://github.com/TYPO3/CmsComposerPackageGenerator/pull/19 however this can't currently be done due to a to low PHP version on the server.

Comment: Yes, this file contains the all the information composer needs, including the autoload information. Nothing else is evaluated for "typo3-ter" packages.

However, since quite some time now the autoload section of composer.json in extensions **is** evaluated when building this information. Thus this part of the composer.json is **not** ignored

Comment: You mentioned that "Nothing else is evaluated for typo3-ter packages" – is this some "special" behaviour? How do you ensure this "special" behaviour. Is there something like a Composer Plugin involved?

Comment: everything is done here: https://github.com/TYPO3/CmsComposerPackageGenerator when generating the composer repository